# Upload file to ftp - iOS

Tags: ios, ftp

I use [SimpleFTPSample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html) to upload files, but i have problem with line:

```
ftpStream = CFWriteStreamCreateWithFTPURL(NULL, (__bridge CFURLRef) urlOfHost);
        assert(ftpStream != NULL);
```

It always NULL, i dont know why? hostUrl is OK but nothing happen to ftpStream and i get the assert.

URL:

```
urlOfHost = [[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate] smartURLForString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"ftp://wd150.1host.co.il/%@", orderKey]];

    success = (urlOfHost != nil);

    if (success) {
        // Add the last part of the file name to the end of the URL to form the final 
        // URL that we're going to put to.

        urlOfHost = CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateCopyAppendingPathComponent(NULL, (__bridge CFURLRef) url, (__bridge CFStringRef) [filePath lastPathComponent], false)
                                 );
        NSLog (@"%@", [urlOfHost description]);
        success = (urlOfHost != nil);
    }
```

Can someone know?

Thank's from advance.

Comment: Show us how you create your `urlOfHost`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you added this potion in PutController to your migration program. The following will solve simpeFTPsample "File read error"

```
@implementation PutController{    
     uint8_t   _buffer[kSendBufferSize];    
}        
 -(uint8_t *)buffer{        
 return self->_buffer;    
}
```

If you no insert this portion in your program.

```
 bytesRead = [self.fileStream read:self.buffer maxLength:kSendBufferSize];
```